# Import CSV/XLS data to Webform?

Tags: 6, webforms, importing-exporting

Is there a way to import records into [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) database from user uploaded CSV/XLS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked well for us: [Webform Import](http://drupal.org/project/webform_import)

> Allows delimited data files to be imported as submission (results) into webforms.
>
> This is useful for importing submissions from other systems in to Webform. Can also be used to Edit submissions via Export / Import as long as the CSV has the SID column filled.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way? Yes.

There isn't any ready made solution though, you would have to read the data yourself and insert it into the database. Since webform has a dynamic use of the database, it would be tricky, since a user could change the webform and break imports.